# Using WHERE with Group By and Having

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have a table with 3 columns `(a, b, c)` with following values:

```
+---+------+---+
| a |  b   | c |
+---+------+---+
| 1 |  5   | 1 |
| 1 | NULL | 1 |
| 2 | NULL | 0 |
| 2 | NULL | 0 |
| 3 | NULL | 5 |
| 3 | NULL | 5 |
+---+------+---+
```

**My desired output:** 3

I want to select only those distinct values from column a for which every single occurrence of this value has NULL in column b given that value in c is not 0. Therefore from my desired output, "1" won't come in because there is a "5" in column b even though there is a NULL for the 2nd occurrence of "1". And "2" won't come in because the value of c is 0

The query that I'm using currently which is not working:

```
SELECT a FROM tab WHERE c!=0 GROUP BY a HAVING COUNT(b) = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `HAVING` clause:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/3535/0)

```
SELECT a
FROM tbl
GROUP BY a
HAVING
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN b IS NOT NULL OR c = 0 THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 END
    ) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the `having` clause that you want:

```
select a
from table t
group by a
having count(case when c <> 0 then b end) = 0 and
       max(c) > 0
```

This assumes that `c` is non-negative.

However, it is not entirely clear why "2" doesn't meet your condition. There are no rows where "c" is not zero.  Hence, all such rows have `NULL` values.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (
    A INT
    ,B INT
    ,C INT
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 1,5,1
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 1,NULL,1
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 2,NULL,0
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 2,NULL,0
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 3,NULL,5
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 3,NULL,5

SELECT
    a,max(b) [MaxB],max(C) [MaxC]
FROM @Table
GROUP BY A
HAVING max(b) IS NULL AND ISNULL(max(C),1)<>0
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you've got 3 answers already, I decided to contribute my 2c...

The query from Ghost comes out most efficient when I check in SQL Server Query analyzer, however, I suspect if your data-set changes that Ghost's query may not be exactly as you require based on what you've written.

I think the query below is what you're looking for at the lowest execution cost in SQL, just basing this on your written requirements as opposed to the data example you've provided (*Note: This queries performance is similar to Felix and Gordon's answers, however, I haven't included a conditional "case" statement in my having clause.*).

```
SELECT DISTINCT(a) FROM intTable 
GROUP BY a
HAVING SUM(ISNULL(b,0))=0 AND SUM(c)<>0
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I believe `DISTINCT` has no power here

Comment: How did you test this exactly?

Comment: Yes, you're correct, it's redundant based on the group by clause, should've removed it but I modified the query a couple of times while working it out so it got left in there.

Comment: @Felix - I ran it against the sample data set a few times and then looked at the performance and steps required in the query-plan analyzer.

Comment: Oh, that's not quite enough to test though. Try testing it with million rows.

Comment: @FelixPamittan - LOL, Whilst in an enterprise environment I'd be sure to test against large data subsets, when responding to questions on StackOverflow (which I don't get paid for) I generally tend to take an all-care no responsibility or "best-effort" attitude to (most of) my answers.